# The equivalent of C# ASCII code in PHP language

Tags: c#, php, ascii, rsa

I want to implement this block code in PHP for bank payment.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

```
ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

string dataString = "Data to Sign";
‬
byte[] originalData = ByteConverter.GetBytes(dataString);

byte[] signedData;

RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

String PrivateKey= File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\PrivateKey.xml");

RSAalg.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);

signedData = Key.SignData(originalData,SHA1.Create());

String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData, 0, signedData.Length);
‬
```

I have tried , but I did not get any results.
I get an sign error as a result of the request.

```
$baseString = "Data to Sign";
$signedData = null;
$privateKey = file_get_contents(config_path("PrivateKey.pem"));
$privateKeyResource = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);

$signature = null;

if (openssl_sign($baseString, $signedData, $privateKeyResource, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1))
            $signature = base64_encode($signedData);
```

Comment: If you get an error, you need to tell us exactly what it says, and which code line caused it. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: In the PHP code, sign `$baseString` and not `$originalData`. If the keys are identical (*PrivateKey.xml* in XML format and *PrivateKey.pem* in PEM encoding) both codes generate the same signature. If not, check if the keys are really identical.

Comment: `Key.SignData`, What is Key here?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is wrong encoding of `dataString` / `$baseString`

The default string encoding in C# is UTF-16, in php however the encoding of a string is automatically ASCII, yet if not supported char appear in the string the encoding changed automatically to UTF-8 - so it depends what string the `$baseString` contain, you can check with `mb_detect_encoding` method if the encoding is still ASCII as expected.